# How improve my if statements in a route [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

```
app.get('/dashboard/:page/:param',function(req, res) {
    var page = parseInt(req.param("page"));
    var param = req.param('param');

    data = {};
    data.page = page;

    if (!param) {
        data.nextPage = page + 1;
        data.prevPage = page - 1;

        MyModel.find().sort('brand').skip((page-1)*11).limit(11).exec(function(err, result) {
            res.render('index1', {
                data: data,
                result: result,
            });
        });
    } 
    else {
        data.nextPage = page + 1 + '/' + encodeURIComponent(param);
        data.prevPage = page - 1 + '/' + encodeURIComponent(param);

        MyModel.find({
               _id: param
            }).sort('brand').skip((page-1)*11).limit(11).exec(function(err, result) {
            res.render('index2', {
                data: data,
                result: result,
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I have this route, and i am using for rendering two pages.

If the page have a param, i want find the id in my database and render de index2, if not i just want render the index.

My question is simple: This is a good way of resolve this problem? Or should i move the else to another route??

Can i improve this to be more dry???

Comment: I'd move the `else` to another route. `app.get('/dashboard/:page/:param` and `app.get('/dashboard/:page/`

Comment: this is the better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this looks cleaner for you?

```
app.get('/dashboard/:page/:param', function (req, res) {
  var page = parseInt(req.param("page"));
  var param = req.param('param');

  data = {
    page: page,
    nextPage: page + 1 + param ? '/' + encodeURIComponent(param) : null,
    prevPage: page - 1 + param ? '/' + encodeURIComponent(param) : null
  };

  MyModel.find(param ? {_id: param} : undefined)
    .sort('brand')
    .skip((page - 1) * 11)
    .limit(11)
    .exec(function (err, result) {
      res.render(param ? 'index2' : 'index1', {
        data: data,
        result: result
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: is working.. but.. can you please rewrite with normal javascript to help me understand??

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by normal javascript?